# How to scrape the lowest price of hotel of a given area from kayak.com?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, request, beautifulsoup

So i have to scrape the least deal of hotel from this metasearch engine. But unable to to do that. All i'm getting is empty list while i'm finding elements with classes. Though request is fetching the correct html that i want. I do not know what to do?
Here is my code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jul 09 13:30:55 2016

@author: sroy
"""

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.kayak.co.in/hotels/Kolkata,India-c44834/2016-07-09/2016-07-10/2guests"
headers = {
'Accept':"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
'Accept-Encoding':"gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
'Accept-Language':"en-US,en;q=0.8",
'Cache-Control':"max-age=0",
'Connection':"keep-alive",
'DNT':1,
'Host':"www.kayak.co.in",
'Referer':"https://www.kayak.co.in/hotels",
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':1,
'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text.encode('utf-8'))


hotel_name = soup.find_all(".title")
price_elems = soup.find_all(".price")

for hotel in hotel_name:
    i=0
    print hotel_name[i]
    print price_elems[i]
    i+=1
```

It is printing nothing. Don't know why. What's the prob

Comment: Where are you entering a check in/out date or the place?

Comment: in the url https://www.kayak.co.in/hotels

Answer (score 2):

You are using [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), but passing them to `find_all()` method instead of `select()`:

```
hotel_name = soup.select(".title")
price_elems = soup.select(".price")
```

Though, I still think you would need a *real browser* since it is quite a dynamic site. In any case, make sure to study Terms of Use and stay on the legal side.

Comment: <div class="col-1-2 title">
<i class="bookmark"></i>
<span id="RAl4-headerTitle">Client-side templating here</span>
</div>
<span class="price"></span>
<div class="col-1-2 title">
<i class="bookmark"></i>
<span id="RAl4-headerTitle">Client-side templating here</span>
</div>
<span class="price"></span>
<div class="col-1-2 title">
<i class="bookmark"></i>
<span id="RAl4-headerTitle">Client-side templating here</span>
</div>
<span class="price"></span>

Comment: This is the output i'm getting

Comment: @catch_me yeah, this why I have this note in the answer :)

Comment: There is some ajax calling in the website. I think i have to fetch that. But can't finding it